# how to use sed to delete the path?

Tags: sed, path

The contents of file:

```
/usr/local/foo/test
/usr/local/foo/testlog
```

how to use sed to delete one of them?

```
FSNAME=/usr/local/foo/test OR /usr/local/foo/testlog
sed -i "s@${FSNAME}@EXCLUSIVE@;/\<EXCLUSIVE\>/d" /tmp/file
```

this does not work, please help me?
thks

Comment: What would the desired result be? What is the result you get with your attempts?

Comment: What is the environment? Bash?

Comment: Could you confirm or reject the idea that you want a random choice between the two mentioned possible values?

Comment: delete the entire path  of the match by using a bash script to process the file.
The PATH is a variable to pass to script

Comment: Please show some examples of how you intend to use this. Give sample inputs. Show desired outputs. Show in contrast to that the outputs you currently get. That would really make the question less unclear.

Comment: script 1:NFS_SRV=xxxx
BASE_FILE=/etc/fstab
BASE_NAME=$1
NAME="/home/data/nfs/"${BASE_NAME}

mount xxxx $NAME nfs defaults 0 0
echo "${NFS_SRV} $NAME nfs defaults 0 0" >> ${BASE_FILE}

Comment: script 2:BASE_NAME=$1
NAME="/home/data/nfs/"${BASE_NAME}
BASE_FILE=/etc/fstab

umount -lf $NAME
According to the full path (example $NAME)to delete records

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
FSNAME=$(echo "/usr/local/foo/test /usr/local/foo/testlog" | xargs shuf -n1 -e)
sed -i.bak "s:$FSNAME:EXCLUSIVE:;/EXCLUSIVE/d" file
```

the `shuf` command will allow you to choose randomly between the 2 paths,
then the `sed` command will delete the line containing only this path.

**test** (without editing the file)

[image]

Comment: Interesting interpretation of the question that OP wants one of the two strings deleted after random choice, along with the whole line. But isn't it a guess? I do not see which part of the question implies a random selection.

Comment: @Yunnosch: hahaha If this is the case I will just delete it or adapt it ;-) I love doing some coding and helping people so doesn't really matter xD

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want

Comment: @charnet1019 could you add some exlanations about how your file is selected? try the first path if it exists use that one else use the other one?